# \baselineskip not changed within block

Tags: pdftex, fontsize, block, baseline

This really puzzles me: Attempting to set the baseline in a block (delimited by `{` and `}`) doesn't seem to have an effect for typed text, but works when a command creates the text.

### Question

What are the rules here?

### MWE (also [on GitHub](https://github.com/krlmlr/lm-template/tree/size-in-block))

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\section{Normal size}

This is a sample of typed text in normal size and with a normal baseline skip -- nothing special.

\section{Size changed in block}

  {\fontsize{15}{20}\selectfont
Here, the baseline skip has been altered in a block delimited by curly braces. The font size has changed, but the baseline skip is weird.
  }

\section{Size changed outside of block}

  \fontsize{15}{20}\selectfont
Everything works as expected outside a block: The baseline skip is considerably larger here.

\section{Size restored}

\normalsize
This is a sample of typed text in normal size and with a normal baseline skip -- nothing special.

\section{Size changed in block for Lorem Ipsum}

  {\fontsize{15}{20}\selectfont\lipsum[1]}
  
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of MWE]

Comment: Put a `\par` at the end of block like `...test test\par
  }`

Comment: Inside the block you *must* have a paragraph break before the typesetting of the paragraph begins. So, issue an explicit `\par`, or leave a blank line before closing the group.

Comment: Can we close it?

Comment: @HarishKumar: Just saw the other question. Thanks.

Comment: @Harish: Yes, please, by all means..